# Unity Container: use ContainerControlledLifetimeManager by default for "Resolve" method group

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, singleton, unity-container

How to fill TODO to make this test pass?

```
class MyClass { }

[Test]
public void Singleton_by_default_test()
{
    var parentContainer = GetUnityContainer();        
    var container = parentContainer.GetChildContainer();

    // TODO: Add magic here (but do NOT explicitly register MyClass in container!)

    Assert.AreSame(container.Resolve<MyClass>(), container.Resolve<MyClass>());
}
```

**Update:**
There is a way that uses inheritance.

```
public class SingletonContainer : UnityContainer
{
    public override object Resolve(Type t, string name)
    {
        var obj = base.Resolve(t, name);
        RegisterInstance(t, name, obj, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I am using *container.GetChildContainer()* to get container instance so this method does not suite me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see where you are going with this.  Interesting problem.

I think you can do what you are doing with a Unity Behavior Extension.  Here's a great article on the design of Unity that describes the job of certain elements of Unity that a lot of people don't know about:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140062.aspx

The Unity Container basically uses a "strategy chain" when handling a resolve request.  One of the strategies in the chain is the `LifetimeStrategy`.

The easiest thing to do would be to create a new strategy and insert it in the chain before the `LifetimeStrategy` so that when your strategy gets a chance to look at the type, it can register a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager for that type in the current container. It will get to the LifetimeStrategy and there will already be a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager registered for that type.

It might look like this:

```
public class MakeEverythingSingletonStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
     public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
     {
          Type objectType = BuildKey.GetType(context.BuildKey);
          context.PersistentPolicies.Set<ILifetimePolicy>(
                  new SingletonLifetimePolicy(), 
                  context.BuildKey);

     }
}
```

You should be able to apply this configuration to the sub container using the `Configure<T>` method, passing in a configuration class that adds this new extension.

I found a good sample of someone on Stackoverflow implementing a custom BuilderStrategy:

[Custom object factory extension for Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380375/custom-object-factory-extension-for-unity/1388522#1388522)

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as singleton.
You can use the following conffiguration for your MyClass:*

```
<type type="MyClass" mapTo="MyClass">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>
```

Comment: You are registering the type explicitly. I don't want to know in advance all types I'm gonna need.